# Delete character from the beginning Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I want to delete the characters from the beginning:

```
If TxtNumberListScan.Text.Contains(",") Then
    TxtNumberListScan.Text = TxtNumberListScan.Text.Replace(",", " ")
End If
```

How to apply that code and how that use for i want?

Textbox1:Text =

```
2019-09-22 / 22:40  4, 9, 11, 14, 15, 24, 28, 30, 31, 32, 43, 46, 56, 61, 64, 65, 67, 68, 71, 78
    2019-09-22 / 15:00  2, 8, 11, 15, 17, 25, 33, 34, 44, 48, 49, 50, 52, 60, 61, 62, 69, 70, 74, 77
    2019-09-21 / 22:40  1, 4, 8, 9, 10, 21, 23, 24, 25, 32, 40, 43, 52, 54, 55, 61, 68, 72, 73, 75
    2019-09-21 / 15:00  5, 6, 12, 13, 18, 24, 26, 28, 29, 32, 40, 46, 50, 52, 56, 62, 63, 65, 70, 74
```

Output: what do i expect: Textbox2.Text=

```
4, 9, 11, 14, 15, 24, 28, 30, 31, 32, 43, 46, 56, 61, 64, 65, 67, 68, 71, 78
2, 8, 11, 15, 17, 25, 33, 34, 44, 48, 49, 50, 52, 60, 61, 62, 69, 70, 74, 77
1, 4, 8, 9, 10, 21, 23, 24, 25, 32, 40, 43, 52, 54, 55, 61, 68, 72, 73, 75
5, 6, 12, 13, 18, 24, 26, 28, 29, 32, 40, 46, 50, 52, 56, 62, 63, 65, 70, 74
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know how the data in the TextBox is created, but it looks like you're using the TextBox as the primary store for the data, and this is almost always a bad thing. You would be better creating a Class that can hold each line of data, and a List of that Class. You can then populate your TextBox with the data you want

Comment: Do you have all that text in one textbox? In case one line is one textbox and characters at the beginning are still in the same format, just use TextBox1.Text.Remove(0,18)

Comment: i already answered this question for you, why did you post the same?

Comment: I was downvoted for answering you correctly so i'm not doing the same here, go to your previous post and use my answer.

Comment: Is your textbox multiline?